# Turn off the second builtin Nodemcu 0.9 led

Tags: led, nodemcu

I'm making a low energy consumption device so I'd like to turn off all the led when I'm idle.

Unfortunately the nodemcu turn on a blue led while I'm idle (during `delay(ms)`)

Here is my code:

```
#define LED    16

void setup() {
  initialSetup();
  //Turn off the built-in led
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  //Here I do everything
  doStuff();
  //GO TO SLEEP
  delay(3600000);
}
```

The led that turn on during delay is the one near to D0 pin.

The led that I can control and so turn off (pin #16 -> D0) is near the 5v pin.

It's possible to completely turn off all led to consume less?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this link which shows your second LED exactly (the image is for v1.0, I have v0.9 and the code below works just the same in this situation):

'Onboard LEDs? NodeMCU's got two!':

https://lowvoltage.github.io/2017/07/09/Onboard-LEDs-NodeMCU-Got-Two

Quote:

> ESP-12 LED Blink:
>
> ```
>  void setup() {
>         pinMode(2, OUTPUT);     //Initialize GPIO2 pin as an output
>  }
>
>  void loop() {
>    digitalWrite(2, LOW);   // Turn the LED on by making the voltage LOW   
>    delay(1000);            // Wait for a second
>    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH 
>    delay(2000);            // Wait for two seconds
>  }
> ```

Or write it like this (ie. using 'D4' rather than '2'):

> ESP-12 LED Blink:
>
> ```
>  void setup() {
>         pinMode(**D4**, OUTPUT);     //Initialize GPIO2 pin as an output
>  }
>
>  void loop() {
>    digitalWrite(**D4**, LOW);   // Turn the LED on by making the voltage LOW   
>    delay(1000);            // Wait for a second
>    digitalWrite(**D4**, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH 
>    delay(2000);            // Wait for two seconds
>  }
> ```

Regards, Geoff

Comment: Thank you, I've already read that link and it talks about nodemcu 1.0, mine is nodemcu 0.9 and pin #2 correspond to port D4 and does NOT turn off any led

Comment: I have a NodeMCU v0.9 and have just tested it.  Referring to the pin as '2' or 'D4' both cause the LED you describe to flash...

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right! I used that port also for another sensor so it remains always on. Now I wired the sensor to port D5 and I've no problem! Thank you, you have the best answer!